# How to download video from links by use flutter

Tags: flutter

I try to create app by this app users can past link of YouTube and download the video in him phone. The code is work now but there are one problem in it. after download video I see it in folder but it's not working I get a message saying it's corrupt when I try to turn it on. Also I see the size of video coming just as KB that is not correct should by size too large because the video is too large time so the size must come as mb so I don't know what is the problem in my code.

Can anyone help me. Thanks

```
class DownloadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DownloadPageState createState() => _DownloadPageState();
}

class _DownloadPageState extends State<DownloadPage> {
  TextEditingController _linkController = TextEditingController();
  bool _isLoading = false;
  double _progress = 0;

  Future<void> _downloadVideo(String link) async {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });

    // Check for storage permission
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      await Permission.storage.request();
    }

    // Get the directory to store the video
    final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
    final filePath = directory!.path + '/video.mp4';

    // Download the video
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse (link));
    var file = File(filePath);
    await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      _progress = 0;
    });

    // Show a success message
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Download Complete'),
        content: Text('Video has been saved to $filePath'),
        actions: [
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Download Video'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              controller: _linkController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Enter YouTube link',
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16.0),
            _isLoading
                ? Column(
              children: [
                LinearProgressIndicator(
                  value: _progress,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                Text('$_progress %'),
              ],
            )
                : ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('Download'),
              onPressed: () {
                _downloadVideo(_linkController.text);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are trying to download a youtube video by the url, but the youtube video is not the url, it is embedded, so you need a external service to download the video by youtube url.

Comment: Hi @Maikzen Can you explain more

Comment: Check this github project: https://github.com/rizkyghofur/youtube_downloader, there is a example of that